# Geolocation insert into sql

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysqli

I want to parse users geolocation into my database.

In my database there are 2 rows called: latitude and longitude, I want the location to be stored into those rows.

Here is the HTML5 API that gets the location:

```
<script>
    var x=document.getElementById("demo");
    function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } else {
            x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
        }

    function showPosition(position) {
        x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
    }

    getLocation();

</script>
```

Here is the page that has the submit form

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="fui-cross"></span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><center>Post</center></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="parse_post.php" method="post" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input name="post_type" type="hidden" value="a" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="description" rows="6" maxlength="450" placeholder="write something"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pull-right">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">          
                        <div id="demo" onLoad=""></div>          
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <input name="" type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Post" onclick="javascript:return validateMyForm();"/> 
                            <input name="uid" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>" />
                            <input name="upass" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['userpass']; ?>" />        
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated 
Thanks

Comment: As a side note, make sure you handle the case where no location is returned. The Location API is optional and prompts the user giving them the chance to deny sending you this information. Make sure you account for the case where you get no value back.

Comment: So whats the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#Demo` is not a form field, so when you submit it nothing will be passed to the server. Try this instead

```
<input id="demo" type="text" />
```

Script

```
<script>
    var x=document.getElementById("demo");
    function getLocation()
    {
        if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
        else
        {
            x.value = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position)
    {
        x.value ="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
    }
    getLocation();

</script>
```

**UPDATE**

I figured there'd be more to this. Doesn't make sense to send those values as a combined string. Do this instead:

```
<input id="latitude" name="latitude" type="text" />
<input id="longitude" name="longitude" type="text" />
```

Script

```
<script>
    function getLocation()
    {
        if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
    }

    function showPosition(position)
    {
        document.getElementById("latitude").value = position.coords.latitude; 
        document.getElementById("longitude").value = position.coords.longitude; 
    }
    getLocation();

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Parsing the latitude and longitude  into my latitude and longitude rows in my database using sql. 
what woud be the propper way. in parse_post.php:     $longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
$latitude =  $_POST['latitude'];$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO forum_posts (latitude, longitude) 
     VALUES('$post_author','$member_id','$latitude','$longitude')") or die (mysql_error());

Comment: once we get the location data from the user it is better to store it for the entire session so we can use it on other pages. Is there an easy solution for this?

Comment: use the PHP Session variable. There are lots of examples online